# Add an "e-mail button" already filled out to a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, email, button

I was trying to create a button that opens e-mail with an already written e-mail, ready to be simply sent without further work from the clicker side.

I wrote a first code that didn't work, re-wrote in another way, then passed on ChatGPT (yeah I needed help) and it still doesn't work (button is there, but nothing happens when I click it).

This is what I came up with at the end:

```
<button id="emailButton">Click to Email</button>

<script><br />
  document.getElementById("emailButton").addEventListener("click", function () {<br />
    var destinationEmail = "email@email.com";<br />
    var emailSubject = "Your email subject here";<br />
    var emailBody = "Your pre-filled message here";</p>
<p>    var emailLink = "mailto:" + destinationEmail + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(emailSubject) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(emailBody);<br />
    window.location.href = emailLink;<br />
  });<br />
</script>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work, it looks correct (I'm not the most experienced person tho). Maybe it's a mistake about how I added it on Wordpress?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have br tags within your script tag.
Remove them, and it should work fine.

If you are starting with development, please install a code editor like VsCode (it's free) so you will notice issues like this.

Comment: I did the changes that you have suggested (and tried it on VsCode). On VsCode when I run it it works, but when I transpose it on WordPress the button still does not work! The button is there, but when I click it nothing happens!

Comment: Then probably the editor you use in Wordpresss add's to br tags. Maybe try creating an actual link with and "a" tag and set the href attribute to: "mailto:info@email.com?subject=The%20subject%20of%20the%20email&body=The%20body%20of%20the%20mail"